# How to put personal PNG dataset into Sci-Kit Learn for Image Identification?

Tags: python, machine-learning, png, scikit-learn

I am attempting to create a Python program that will identify images and I am using the Sci-Kit Learn machine learning package. I have already done a tutorial they provide for identifying digits (this is the link to the tutorial: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html#introduction). Now, I would like to use Sci-Kit Learn's `svm.SVC` classifier to identify images from my own dataset of PNG images, but I do not know how to do so. I read that the `fit(X, y)` method needs to take in `[n_samples, n_features]` array and a `[n_samples]` array; however, I do not quite understand what they mean by `n_samples` and `n_features`. Here is relevant code from my program:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import glob
event_png_pair = []
for file in glob.glob('../../Pictures/Trial/*.png'):
    img = Image.open(file, 'r')
    ''' Some image resizing code '''
    img_conv = img.convert("L")
    datum = np.array(img_conv)
    ''' Some name parsing below '''
    name = file
    name = name.replace('.png', '')[::-1]
    name_list = list(name)
    number_char_list = name_list[:name_list.index('_')]
    number_list = number_char_list[::-1]
    event_number = int(''.join(number_list))
    ''' Create tuple with event number and corresponding np array from image '''
    event_png_pair.append((event_number, datum))
```

Clearly the above isn't really that helpful, it just shows how I went about interpreting data from the PNG image. Could anybody provide any guidance on how to create a dataset that could be interpreted by Sci-Kit Learn?

UPDATE: I am now gonna try to create a dataset like the digits dataset except with my own images. I will make `n_samples` the number of images and `n_features` the image data. My `target` will be an array `[1, 2]` because I am only trying to distinguish between two types images. If there is any relevant information on how to put an image dataset into Sci-Kit Learn could somebody please provide that information.

Comment: Depending on your images, feeding raw pixels into a classifier will likely not work. You can try it, but you will probably be more successful using feature extraction using scikit-image or a trained convolutional neural network as from sklearn-theano for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use raw pixels as features (as in the digits example) you need to resize / reshape / pad the images to have the same number of pixels for each image. Then you need to flatten each image to a single row, and stack them into an array.
This will only work for very simple, aligned and normalized images.

Comment: I did this, and it worked to some extent however my images are more complicated than the digits dataset so I have memory errors. Is there a better way to analyze more complicated images?

Comment: @Troll_Hunter If you use CNN-s you have no need to flatten images to a single row, simply you can use 2D convolutional layer.

Answer (score 0):

`n_samples` is the number of images.

`n_features` is the image data itself.

You have to create a matrix with the shape `(number of images x number of image points)`, then pass to the classifier.

You have to resize all of your images to a constant, same size like say 256x256 or 128x128, or 96x96 or any size which is suitable to extract relevant information from it. To each images belong (mostly) one (grayscale)  or three (RGB) value representing the given color.

If you really intend to classify images with the highest performance you should use **convolutional network** and you should get a **GPU** with reasonable performance, however the process works with **CPU** too, but much more slower.

Comment: Pixels. All images need to have the same number of pixels.

Comment: @Troll_Hunter You have to resize all of your images to a constant, same size like say 256x256 or 128x128, or 96x96 or any size which is suitable to extract relevant information from it. To each images belong (mostly) one (grayscale)  or three (RGB) value representing the given color.